# Cannot connect using ssh with one PC but ok with another

Tags: ssh

I can connect to a remote server using with one PC, but not with another, where I get

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "*******" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ***** [****] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I have to say that this is a new problem, a few days ago I was able to connect, what could cause this behavior? Why only one PC cannot connect? I  always use the same login. 
Also, I don't know why it looks for identity files in  /root/.ssh, since I am running the command from a normal user

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the right public-key-file. Try to copy them from the working computer to the nonworkinig. They should be somewhere in your home directory. Normally id_rsa.pub.

It also could be solved if you check your known_hosts file and remove the not working one and reconnect your host by:
`ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@remote-system`
To find out which one in the known_hosts file is your nonworking one compare the key from the id_rsa.pub and the entry in the known_hosts file.